# Is my Matlab solution to the below question correct?

Tags: matlab

I am not experienced at all with Matlab and I just wanted to verify that I am doing this correctly. The question is:

Consider the case of a sinusoidal signal whose amplitude is modulated by a train of
pulses:

$$S(t) = \sin(\omega_0 t)P(t)$$
where $P(t)$ is a train of pulses with pulsed
values of $0$ and $1$. Lets us set $\omega_0 = 10^9 \cdot 2\pi \,\texttt{rad/s}$, and period of $P(t)=10^{-6} \,\texttt{s}$ with a duty cycle $D = 10 \%$.

Plot $S(t)$ as function of $t$ for at least $10 \,\texttt{s}$

The rest of the assignment deals with plotting spectrums but I need to make sure that the first portion is correct.
My solution to this is:

```
t = linspace(0,10e-6,1000);

x=0.5*(square(2*pi*1000000.*t,10)+1); 
% change square wave to go from 0 to 1 vs -1 to 1

Amp = 1;

y = Amp*sin(2*pi*1e9.*t); 
 %1 GHz signal

S = x.*y; 

plot(t,S);

xlabel('time');

ylabel('product wave');
```

I ended up getting a plot that had no negative samples of the sinusoid.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've edited your question for better formatting. Make sure everything looks right please.

Comment: It seems that you're trying to plot $10^{10}$ periods of the sine wave -- are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, the assignment specifically asks that we plot the product of the sine wave and the PWM signal for 10 microseconds, it just got edited out.

Comment: Also, the sampling frequency in your code is $10^5$. Does that agree with the sampling theorem?

Comment: 10 microseconds is more reasonable, but still $10^4$ periods...

Answer (score 2):

Your values seem unreasonable to me. You want to generate a 1 gigahertz sine wave. If you want, say, ten samples per cycle then your signal sample rate must be Fs = 10 gigahertz. A ten second sequence whose sample rate is 10 gigahertz would be 100 gigasamples in length. Your computer doesn’t have enough memory to accommodate such lengthy sine wave sequence.

Comment: Oops, I got a number wrong. Your signal sample rate must be Fs = 10 gigahertz. A ten second sequence whose sample rate is 10 gigahertz would be 100 gigasamples in length. Your computer doesn’t have enough memory to accommodate such lengthy sine wave sequence.